# Zoom out to show hidden entries

Tags: mpandroidchart

I'm struggling to get all of my entries showing in my chart. Here's what it looks like

[image]

PinchZoom is enabled, but I can't zoom out anymore.

Is there some way to programmatically zoom out more, or to set the bounds of the view?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation of the YAxis](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/YAxis).

There are a lot of ways to extend the range of the axis. However I am pretty sure something is wrong with your setup.